# Button input click trigger jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason my jQuery code is not able to find the button by class.

This is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".deleteItem").click(function () {
                alert("Handler for .click() called.");
            });
        });
```

The html I have for the button:

```
<input type="button" value="Remove" class="deleteItem btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right" id="testDeleteItem">
```

When the page is loading, the button is not recognized. The button is in hidden div and its only shown when the user is hovering over a control.

What do I need to change to make this work?

Comment: is the button dynamically loaded?

Comment: Is the button in an iframe?

Comment: @AmmarCSE the button is dynamically loaded, yes, via c# code. but thats all done while the page elements are created on page_load, nothing async.

Comment: Is jQuery included and is that JS included?

Comment: simply use `'$(".deleteItem").on('click', function () {'`

Comment: @Stryner no, its not in an iframe

Comment: Does it work if you try to get button by ID? $('#testDeleteItem')... ?

Comment: @Zealander no it doesn't recognize the button by ID as well

Comment: You say button is in hidden control. Can you post code that shows/hides the button?

Comment: FYI @ (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) : As a best practice, we highly recommend using the <button> element whenever possible to ensure matching cross-browser rendering.

Among other things, there's a bug in Firefox <30 that prevents us from setting the line-height of <input>-based buttons, causing them to not exactly match the height of other buttons on Firefox.

Comment: I would also strive to never pre-class an element with anything but pure bootstrap class declarations in the given order twitter's team defined in the documentation linked in previous comment.  You could alternatively use your string of bootstrap classes starting with "btn....." and id the element with id="deleteItem" that would make it much cleaner, and also clarify your selector.  Lastly, any bootstrap selectors are dot-notation classes when selecting ie: $("deleteItem.btn.btn-danger.btn-xs.pull-right" is the correct class based elem query in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use delegation for dynamically loaded content

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.deleteItem', function () {
            alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    });
});
```

Comment: @Popnoodles, the OP stated the content is dynamically loaded

Comment: Your syntax was wrong

Comment: @Popnoodles, oh! (facepalm), thanks for the correction

Comment: Thanks, this is working.

Comment: @Laziale (I don't want to over-edit the answer) this means that `document`, which exists the jQuery is executed, listens for the click, but the behaviour is attributed to `.deleteItem` which did not exist, and therefore couldn't be told to listen for the click event, at the time the jQuery was executed.